# VS2015 preview: NDK_ROOT is not defined

Tags: c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install VS2015 preview to see how to develop a c++ android app.

The online secondary installer is very slow so I cancelled it and tried to install the tools separately one by one. It *seemed* to be OK.

Then I created a c++ project for android and tried to compile it, but I got an error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Android1.NativeActivity, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
1>  JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25"
1>  NDK_ROOT=
1>TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "clang.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I guess the problem is that `NDK_ROOT` is empty, but I have installed the NDK and defined `NDK_ROOT` manually in windows system environment variables.So I guess it needs to defined somewhere else, maybe in the registry?

Anyone with a successful VS2015 c++ android environment could check where `NDK_ROOT` is defined in your system?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Go to Visual Studio 2015/Tools/Options/Cross Platform/Android et set folders for : Android SDK, Android NDK, Apache Ant, Java JDK.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted VS to use my existing Android tools and changing string key 'NDK_HOME' at 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\VS\SecondaryInstaller\AndroidNDK' did the trick.

Maybe you can add it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set environment variables "NDKROOT"  rather than "NDK_ROOT",and the variables's value is your real ndk path

Comment: Incredible! Now, isn't that obvious!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Android tools installed already, go to Programs and Features and find **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Preview Secondary Installer**, select it and click Change. When it brings up a list of secondary tools to install, there's no need to change the defaults that are selected. Just click Next and then Install.

After you do that your project will find clang and build correctly.

Comment: Where is the secondary installer for CTP 5?

Comment: @user8709 my answer is from before the release of CTP5